# Sum value from different view - laravel

Tags: laravel

I am loading a view and later returning it as a JSON to the frontend, and loading that data directly into the view.
This looks like:

### controller

```
foreach($grouped as $gk => $data){
       //loading view(_table)
    $body = \View::make('admin.floor-stack._table')
         ->with('data',$data)
        ->render();
        $body_str =  $body_str .$body;
}
    return response()->json([
        'body'  =>  $body_str 
]);
```

### _table

```
<?php 
  //after other calculations
  $val = xxx
?>
<div>
  <table>
  //table data here
  </table>
</div>
```

### frontend

```
<script>
//on success of ajax. resp is the response from ajax.
$('#tableDiv').html('resp.body')
<script>
```

As you can see, each `_table` view will possess `$val` and my requirement is that I need to sum these `$val` from all `_table` that loaded in that foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an extra hidden `tr` to table in `_table.blade.php`. Then keep the `$val` in a `td` of the hidden row.

```
<tr style="display: none;"><td class="table-sum">{{$val}}</td></tr>
```

After loading in the response json, sum all the value of `td` having class `table-sum` you will get the desired value.

```
<script>
    let sum = 0;
    $('.table-sum').each(function (index) {
        let value = parseInt($(this).text());
        sum += isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    });
</script>
```